# Memory mapped files replace IO path

Tags: c++

I have an exe program, it load file by absolute path
fopen("config\script.txt")
So I want to write a dll, and call it from exe file above. when dll is called, it will load C:\script.txt to memory, and after that, exe will load script from C drive instead of config\script.txt
Is it possible to map C:\script.txt and replace with IO path (config\script.txt)?
As I read from MS document, it will load from memory first, but not sure that if I can map and replace physical path on drive.

Comment: This `config\script.txt` is not an absolute path - and it is not a exe as well

Comment: I don't believe you can change the path of a file trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a symlink that will redirect `config\script.txt` to some other file.